# Exporting designs for professional magazine printing?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cmyk, print-production

I have several PSDs, each PSD represents a page that makes up a small A6 magazine.

Now firstly, I wanted to ask, do I send the individual *PSD* files to be printed?

If so, what file type is best? (With CMYK)

If not, what should I do? Should I combine them into one InDesign document? (Coulnd't find a way to import the PSD into inDesign)

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Photoshop is rarely, if ever, the proper tool for full pages of a multi-page publication. While it may be easier to use Photoshop for some, that doesn't make it the correct tool to use. Can you use Photoshop, sure. But you shouldn't in most cases. Customarily a "magazine" has a great deal of text and applications such as Indesign or QuarkXPress are specifically created to handle text formatting, layout, and editing much easier than Photoshop.

You can **Place** .psd files into any Indesign document using `File > Place`. You don't "import" .psd files, you *link* to them.

In most cases you deliver a PDF file using job options geared toward printing (PDFx). Ask your printer which job options they prefer.

Comment: Much appreciated on the explanation, printer just told me to set it as CMYK, so I don't know what file extension etc is needed. What do you suggest doing?

Comment: Place the files into one Indesign document and export to PDF/X-1a

Answer (score 3):

The answer to any printing question is:

**Ask your printer.**

That said, PhotoShop is really the wrong tool for magazine publishing. Your printer will likely prefer the InDesign solution. So you'd have to place all of your images into an InDesign document and then send that.

Comment: How will inDesign allow me to Place files? Currently most of the options after clicking "File" are disabled,  how do I correctly set it up to work?